# Is W3C validator is required?

Tags: w3c-validation

I wonder why techie giants like Facebook shows many errors when validated in W3C ([Link](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com))

Is W3C required?

Answer (score 1):

W3C validation is a good idea, but it is not "required". What could "required" possibly mean? I could call my ISP, get a static IP, set up a server, buy a domain, and configure HTTP to return anything I want and call it HTML if I like.

If you're doing web development and have no reason not to get it to pass W3C validation, then you should. Presumably, Facebook had a reason to ignore it - either they wanted to do something that wouldn't pass, or they didn't want to pay their engineers to make it pass, or the engineers who were responsible for it were incompetent, etc.

It's a good idea to get it to validate to ensure that you're conforming to applicable standards so that your site works well in as many standards-compliant browsers as possible.

You think the W3C validation is bad? Tell your browser to always alert you to Javascript errors, enable Javascript debugging, and go to your favorite sites.